# SQL Server - Invalid object name while joining table to itself

Tags: sql-server

I've tried to find an answer to my problem but couldn't find similar example.

I have results from such a query

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT id FROM table
) AS t1
```

Now I would like to join t1 to another instance of itself because I need to shift it. For example if I wanted to compare a row with the previous one. I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT id FROM table
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN t1 AS t2 ON (my conditions)
```

But I get an error that t1 is invalid object name. When I copy my select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT id FROM table
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT id FROM table
) AS t2 ON (my conditions)
```

The above works, but is it not slower than joining to already returned results?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is in correct:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT id FROM table
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN t1 AS t2 ON (my conditions)
```

Because you can't alias an alias. You can do something similar to it using CTE like so:

```
;WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Table   
)
SELECT *
FROM Cte t1
INNER JOIN cte t2 ON --
```

Comment: Totally forgot about CTE, I know of the concept but I guess I didn't understand their possibilities completely. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think your select should be of the form:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [table] t1
LEFT JOIN [table] t2 ON (your conditions)
```

From a performance perspective, this is identical to your last select and to the CTE solution in [Mahmoud's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12707238/390819) (I've reviewed the execution plan for all three in SQL Server).

It might only be a matter of taste, but I find this form to be more readable/maintainable.